# Multiple USB webcam detect in java code

Tags: java, swing, jmf

I have to connect three usb webcams in my system. I wrote code that is able to find only one camera. Others are not being showed. Please anyone help me. How can I detect all usb webcam?

Comment: I assume you've checked that *individually*, any of the cameras is detected? i.e. it's not just that 2 of the cameras aren't compatible with JMF?

Comment: AFAIR it was a limitation of JMF that it could only detect one camera at a time.  Try ..[Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/) or something.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you did not show us your code, so I have no idea how are you trying to connect to the camera.

But my short investigation shows the following. Class `CaptureDeviceManager` has method `getDeviceList(Format format)` that should return you *all* devices that support specified format. It seems that you should use this method, then iterate over resulted vector and user the cameras. I hope this will work for you if you specify correct format.

Comment: Thanks AlexR, I want to need a small program with using "CaptureDeviceManager" and "getDeviceList(Format format)". Thanks Advance.